# Cannot load PHP7 mongodb driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, php-7

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and only pre-installed PHP7 on it. So, I have normally installed and started MongoDB 3.2, but cannot run php driver.

> pecl install mongodb

works correct and currently shows that mongodb 1.2.0 driver is already installed. I have of course added "*extension=mongodb.so*" to php.ini file. So, **php -v** prints an error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.13-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.13-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

I read all SO answers about it, tried to google any information, but still no result. All github opened issues with some kind of this type of error are also contain no answer.

So, how to make it work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with json extension. Take a look at https://github.com/php-ds/extension/issues/2 it must help you

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! I've changed the loading order of modules to be sure that json will be loaded before mongodb.